# I am having an error in xampp I cannot start MYSQL

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am having an error below in **xampp**.

I cannot start **MYSQL**.

> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 ee8 InnoDB: Warning: Using
>   innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be
>   removed in future releases, together with the option
>   innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count
>   buffer pool pages
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is
>   disabled
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use
>   Windows interlocked functions
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib
>   1.2.3
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32
>   instructions
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size
>   = 16.0M
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of
>   buffer pool
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [ERROR] InnoDB: space header page consists of
>   zero bytes in data file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the
>   system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system
>   tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit
>   innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the
>   new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only
>   wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way.
>   But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your
>   precious data!
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function
>   returned error.
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a
>   STORAGE ENGINE failed.
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine:
>   InnoDB
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [ERROR] Aborting
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Binlog end
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'mysql_old_password'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin
>   'mysql_native_password'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
>
> 2014-03-14 14:55:12 5236 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe:
>   Shutdown complete

Answer (score 0):

If you did not delete any thing from data directory or did not change data directory then you can try after below change in your configuration file:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G
```

(1G is just an example keep it at least half of your RAM)

Then share error logs if still not start.

Comment: what configuration file? is it the my.ini?

Comment: download the notepad here. this is the error logs

https://www.mediafire.com/?lywlu92xiudgf3d

so that the my error is not hard to read :)